# Django : django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-errors

I am making a simple blog , I have used the project name as Blogger_Vip
and app name as blog

I have the following code:

In project level module Blogger_Vip :

urls.py contains:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import home_page , contact_page , about_page , register_page , 
login_page

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url('^blog/', include('enc_vip_blog.urls',namespace='enc_vip_blog')),
url(r'^$',home_page,name='home'),
url(r'^login/$',login_page,name='login'),
url(r'^register/$',register_page,name='register'),
url(r'^about/$',about_page,name='about'),
url(r'^contact/$',contact_page,name='contact'),

]
```

views.py contains:

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ContactForm,LoginForm,RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model





def home_page(r):
context = {
    'title':'Hello World!',
    'content':'Welcome to the Home Page!'
}
if r.user.is_authenticated:
    context['premium_content']='Yeahhhh!'
return render(r,'home_page.html',context)

def about_page(r):
context = {
    'title': 'ABOUT PAGE',
    'content': 'Welcome to the About Page!'
}
return render(r,'about_page.html',context)

def contact_page(r):
contact_form = ContactForm(r.POST or None)
context = {
    'title': 'CONTACT PAGE',
    'content': 'Welcome to the Contact Page!',
    'form':contact_form,
    'brand':'new brand',
}
if contact_form.is_valid():
    print(contact_form.cleaned_data)

return render(r,'contacts/view.html',context)

User = get_user_model()
#This captures the default fields of User Model
def register_page(r):
register_form = RegisterForm(r.POST or None)
context = {
    'register_form':register_form
}
if register_form.is_valid():
    username = register_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = register_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    password = register_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
    print(new_user)
    # print(password)
return render(r,'auth/register.html',context)



def login_page(r):
login_form = LoginForm(r.POST or None)
context = {

    'login_form':login_form
}
print('User Logged in :')
print(r.user.is_authenticated)
if login_form.is_valid():
    print(login_form.cleaned_data)
    username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(r,username=username,password=password)
    print("User Logged in:")
    print(r.user.is_authenticated)
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        print(r.user.is_authenticated)
        login(r,user)
        # login_form['login_form']=login_form
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print('Error')


return render(r,'auth/login.html',context)
```

forms.py contains:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model





User = get_user_model()
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
fullname = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(
                                        attrs={'class':'form- 
control','placeholder':'Your name here',
                                               'id':'fullname'}
                                                ),help_text="Max 100 
characters")
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
                                        attrs={'class':'form- 
control','placeholder':'Your email here',
                                               'id':'email'}
                                                ))
content = forms.CharField(max_length=300,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs= 
{'class':'form-control',
                                                       'placeholder':'Leave 
your message here',
                                                       'id':'content'}),
                          help_text='300 characters max')


def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

    if not 'gmail.com' in email:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email must be Gmail id!")
    return email


class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField()
email = forms.CharField()
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm 
Password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

#Unique username constraint setup
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    #Queryset to get all logged in or registered user objects from User 
model
    user_queries = User.objects.filter(username=username)#Got all usernames 
that are already registered
    #Checking if current username matches any other username from the 
results
    if user_queries.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username Exists!')
    return username

# Unique email id constraint setup
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_queries = User.objects.filter(email=email)
    if email_queries.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('This Email Id is taken!')
    return email


#Password confirmation during registration
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    confirmation_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

    if password!=confirmation_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match!")
    return data





class LoginForm(forms.Form):
  username = forms.CharField()
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Now I have an app called as enc_vip_blog:
This contains the following:
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

```
# Create your models here.
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
def published(self):
    return self.get_queryset().filter(publish = True)


class Tag(models.Model):
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200 , unique=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.slug


class Entry(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
short_body = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='Click link to know 
more')
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100 , unique=True)
publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/',null=True,blank=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
objects = EntryManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('enc_vip_blog:detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

#To make admin representations look better override class Meta

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Blog Entry'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Blog Entries'
    #Set ordering to reverse chronological order
    ordering = ['-created']
```

urls.py contains:
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from .views import BlogListView ,BlogDetailView

```
app_name = 'enc_vip_blog'

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view() , name='list'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', BlogDetailView.as_view() , name='detail'),

]
```

Finally to list all I have list.html:

```
{%extends 'base/base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block content%}
<ul>{%for object in object_list%}
    {%include 'blog/card.html' with instance=object%}
   {%endfor%}
   </ul>
   {%endblock%}
```

and card.html:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title"> <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ 
 instance.title }}</a></h5>
  {%if instance.image%}
<a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ instance.image.url }}" style="width: 
  100%;" alt="{{ instance.title }}">
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
  </a>
  {%endif%}
  <p class="card-text">{{ instance.short_body }}</p>
  <p class="Meta">{{ instance.created }}</p>
  <p class="Meta">tagged under {{ instance.tags.all|join:', ' }}</p>
   <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn- 
  primary">View</a>

 </div>
 </div>
```

I want that when the user logs in he/she shud be redirected to homepage and homepage must contain a link saying 'Visit Blog' 
there I have used {%url 'enc_vip_blog:list'%}

and i get the following errors:

```
   django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 
  'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I am trying to find out a link to this detail kind of think...
Also the blog was runs fine if I donot use the namespace stuff 
But still on homepage even hardcoding the url section into href as 
      {%url 'blog/'%} didn't work?

Can anybody help?
Help me with both the problem for namespace and also the hardcoding kind of stuff?

Comment: try this url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$'...........add slash /$ at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), ...)`
And make sure you have slugs in your db just check in the admin panel